# Error in displaying page number in rdlc report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssrs-2008, reporting-services, rdlc

I m getting error while trying to display page numbers using "Globals!PageNumber" in expression.. the place holder is accepting the expression but when i run the report i get #error in the page number field..is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: actually the rpeort was in a different version so i upgraded it to the new version with dll... microsoft.reportviewer.webforms reference set to 10.0 version...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found two workarounds for this problem:

1) Changing Target Framework from 4.0 to 3.5 in the project settings

2) Adding the following line inside the web.config in the system.web section:

`<trust legacyCasModel="true" level="Full"/>`